# 19.04 Dell Precission and fan noise on thunderbolt

Tags: dell, 19.04, fan, thunderbolt

I am running Kubuntu 19.04 on a Dell Precision 3541.
All works well as long I don't use a thunderbolt dock with usb peripherals.
As soon as I authenticate these, the **virtual** temperature rises (acpi/Thermal_Zone/6_pch_cannonlake/Temperature) and the fan runs on 4000 rpm, turning the notebook into an aircraft.

Now I tried the certified 18.04 LTS with a live Stick - the same rise in **virtual** temperature (to the degree), but the fan stays of and the notebook is still cool.

I guess there must be some difference in the fan regulation between releases. I already tried shutting of the fan using i8kutils, but it's coming on again 2 seconds later.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue which happened with various dell business/workstation range. The thunderbolt chip doesn't have any cooling measure so the fan always spin up to cool it. Methods which work for now are under-volt CPU or apply thermal pad to the chip on the main-board of the laptop (or both).

You can find more information here https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/4zajkk/dell_xps_9550_thermal_padding_mod_update/ or other places using google.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Of course the chip gets warm.
The problem with Ubuntu 19.04 is, the fan ramps up, even when there is no load on thunderbolt or the CPU. Just plug in a dock with USB-Controller and hear the fan ramp up at desktop idle.

That's not the case in 18.04 or even Windows 10.
There must be some issue on the fan control or the driver side to cause this.

Comment: There are countless cases with have fan noise with thunderbolt on these Dell with only hub inserted https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-XPS-15-9550-Thunderbolt-and-Fan-Speed/td-p/4761018#.XZQAEdwW6xg.link